# Ajax Load Contact Form and SEO

Tags: seo

Im thinking of creating an Ajax load contact form, so when the user submits a successful form the Thanks! page will load via Ajax Load.

But saying this, if I were to do this, my SEO wouldnt show that the visitor got to the thanks page... would it?

I was thinking if this were the case then I could add my Analytics code to the thanks page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your contact form is typically not a Search Engine Optimization concern.  I've never heard of a site that gets a significant amount of search referral traffic to the contact form.

I believe that Googlebot views the presence of a contact form as a sign of a quality site (similar to having a privacy policy and about us).  For this purpose, I wouldn't imagine that having as AJAX would hurt as long as there were a link on the home page that include the word "contact".

It sounds like you might actually be worried about analytics, not SEO.  Maybe you should rephrase the question?

Comment: Sorry, I was all over the place when i wrote that. We are looking to make sure that Analytics would show that the visitor was successful in getting to the Thanks page when they sent a form